# Adding files to Array from Sub Folders

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsfilemanager

I'm using the following code to add files of a specific extension from a folder to an array.

```
self.fileArray = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil).filter{ filterExtensions.contains($0.pathExtension) }
```

I need to add files from all subfolders within the selected folder/Drive.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get like this :

```
let enumerator = try FileManager.default.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)!.allObjects

self.fileArray = enumerator.filter { filterExtensions.contains(($0 as! URL).pathExtension) } as! [URL]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get url resource key isRegularFileKey to check if the enumerated url is a regular file. You can also set the options to skip hidden files and package descendants, otherwise it will also copy hidden files like .DS_Store:

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
var files: [URL] = []
FileManager.default.enumerator(at: documentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants])?.forEach {
    if let url = $0 as? URL, (try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isRegularFileKey]))?.isRegularFile == true {
        files.append(url)
    }
}
```

---

You can also get all objects returned from the enumerator and conditionally cast them into an array of URLs and then filter the URLs which meets the condition:

```
if let files = (FileManager.default.enumerator(at: documentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants])?.allObjects as? [URL])?
    .filter({
      (try? $0.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isRegularFileKey]))?.isRegularFile == true
}) {
   print(files.count)
}
```

Comment: The URL will always be a directory URL .. since I only allow directory selection in NSOpenPanel.

Comment: A different question .... My application is taking up 18GB of memory when processing large number of images...Should I explicitly dispose off NSImages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156184/discussion-between-techno-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: Actually you have forgotten the the filter.

Comment: Filter for what? Do you need to add all files or just a specific file type?

Comment: I am appending only the files that meet the condition I can also add all of them and filter later

Comment: Whats the advantage of your approach  compared with the other answer.Except the hidden file exclusion ...

Comment: Besides the safety (no forced casting) the other answer will filter also all files that are not directories but don't have a pathExtension. It is hack. You should use the proper method getResourceValues.

Comment: I need to pass a URL parameter as I mentioned before... The URL is the local directory the user selects .

Comment: I will post the code currently I use... After some time

Comment: Just change documentsDirectory with your url

Comment: The enumerator runs for ever when selecting directory containing larger number of files and folders.